# Is it possible to create virtual host on running tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, virtualhost

I am able to make virtual host on tomcat by editing **server.xml** file.But each time i edit **server.xml** i have to restart tomcat.

If i make virtual host by using **host-manager** application of tomcat, **virtual host** configured correctly but disappear after restarting tomcat and also not working properly.

Is there any way to make **virtual host** that can be configured **without restarting** tomcat and don't disappear after restarting tomcat.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not my experience. If I make a virtual host with the host-manager, it is persistent.Off topic.